# Ubuntu 16.04 : Can't Install or Update mesa-vdpau-drivers

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, dependencies, amd-graphics, mesa

First off I was trying to update my system. I got the error that some packages couldn't be updated/installed. The package was mesa-vdpau-drivers and corresponding i386 of the same.

I tried installing the driver manually using the command:
`sudo apt install mesa-vdpau-drivers`

It gives me following on my terminal:
`Some packages could not be installed.`
`This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libomxil-bellagio0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Now I have tried installing the dependency manually, it installs smoothly but when I try the command to install mesa-vdpau, it again shows the same error.
I purged everything of mesa and installed everything from scratch it is still on the same situation.

So, how do I solve this? mesa-vdpau-drivers are needed for a hard kick to my system.

My APU+GPU:
AMD A8 with R5 graphics M230

Any help to solve or pointing me in right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any progress with this, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, had to make a fresh install of Gnome 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dell Inspiron with AMD graphic card, but Ubuntu 16.04 no longer supports it.
After upgrading from 14.04, I encounter similar issue with you, due to the unmet dependency problem. After searching and trying many ways, I make it work as below:
Type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which will gvive the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 25.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 100 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Then type <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue and you'll get:

```
Get:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libvdpau1 amd64 1.1.1-3ubuntu1 [25.5 kB]
Fetched 25.5 kB in 20s (1,259 B/s)      
(Reading database ... 192457 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Setting up libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up vdpau-va-driver:amd64 (0.7.4-5) ...
Setting up va-driver-all:amd64 (1.7.0-1) ...
Setting up vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: can't test it, shifted to Arch Linux.